# How to fetch data from Mongodb using PHP in Codeigniter with particular condition?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a collection timeslots:

```
{
user_id: 123,
Day: 1,
},
{
user_id:242,
Day:2,
},
{user_id:4352,
Day:3,
}
```

Now i am running the code:

```
$collection = $this->mongoci->Vehicle->selectCollection('timeslots');
$cursor = $collection->find(array('day'=>'1'));
```

But it is not working..
How can i get the detail of those collection whose day is 1 or 2 or something else.

Comment: There is not need to SHOUT AT US

Comment: I am assuming the keys are case-sensitive: `day` vs `Day`

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: I meant that i tried both cases,but not able to fetch data. It is not fetching data from mongodb...when i passing the key...
I tried Day to... but also it is not working for dat sir..

Comment: Thanks for your opinion guys...It is resolved.